# Solution manual to Larson's "Problem Solving through Problems"

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, online-resources

I am working through Larson's "Problem Solving through Problems" (http://math.la.asu.edu/~ifulman/mat194/problem-solving.pdf) but many of the problems have neither solutions nor sources included. Does anyone know if there are solutions to those problems somewhere online?

Comment: even if smn knew, they are probably scared to put the link on public. Piracy is a criminal offense.

Comment: @TKM "If a law is unjust, a man is not only right to disobey it, he is obligated to do so." Thomas Jefferson